# Ставится ли запятая перед «чем» в предложении: «Прежде чем мы падем»?

Tags: пунктуация

Из заголовка, наверное, ясно. «Прежде чем мы падем» или «Прежде, чем мы падем»? Голову ломаю. :(

Answer (score 3):

Составной союз ПРЕЖДЕ ЧЕМ расчленяется факультативно, чаще встречается вариант без расчленения. При расчленении повышается значимость придаточной части (отношения между главным и придаточным предложением становятся взаимообусловленными). Если придаточное находится в середине предложения, то союз не может  расчленяться. На расчленение может влиять наличие частиц или наречий, отнесенных к союзу.

Поэтому для окончательного решения, нужно видеть всё предложение.

**Прежде чем** идти в гости, дед обедал. [Сергей Довлатов. Наши (1983)]

**Прежде чем** выбраться из воды, устроил на куст мокрую, облепленную водорослями сумку, из которой лились грязные струи воды. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

Но в непогоду срывай плод **прежде, чем** он обвис...[В. Г. Распутин. Новая профессия (1998)]

Иностранные партнёры, **прежде чем** прийти, подсчитывают, сколько они могут в Россию вложить и сколько при этом здесь продать.